# How to load CSV file into Database with SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I'm currently using SymmetricDS 3.8.27. I have a comma separated file that includes data for a database table. Is it possible to replicate that data from the CSV file into a MySql database table using SymmetricDS? If so, what are the steps I need to take to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use dbimport included in the bin folder to import a csv file.

```
dbimport --format=csv --table=mytable myfile.csv
```

The first line in the file is used to read the column names.